# Querying json that starts with an array

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a JSON that starts with an array and I don't manage to query it.
JSON is in this format:

```
[
{"@id":1,
"field1":"qwerty",
"@field2":{"name":"my_name", "name2":"my_name_2"},
"field3":{"event":[{"event_type":"OP",...}]}
},
{"@id":2..
}
]
```

Any suggestions on how to query this?

If I try to use lateral flatten I don't know what key to use:

```
select 
'???'.Value:@id::string as id
from tabl1
,lateral flatten (tabl1_GB_RECORD:???) as gb_record
```

Comment: can you share with us what have you tried and what you're trying to get from your queries?

Comment: Im trying to query @id, field1 values. I tried to use lateral flatten but doesn't work - I probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL was close but not complete, the following will give you `@id` values

```
with tbl1 (v) as (
 select parse_json('  
 [
 {"@id":1,
 "field1":"qwerty",
 "@field2":{"name":"my_name", "name2":"my_name_2"},
 "field3":{"event":[{"event_type":"OP"}]}
 },
 {"@id":2
 }
 ]')
)  
select t.value:"@id" id from tbl1
, lateral flatten (input => v)  as t
```

Result:

```
id
___
1
2
```

Let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: Thanks. Didnt know about the "input". Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You leverage the field that you want to flatten when the json begins with an array.  Something along these lines:

```
WITH x AS (
SELECT parse_json('[
{"@id":1,
"field1":"qwerty",
"@field2":{"name":"my_name", "name2":"my_name_2"},
"field3":{"event":[{"event_type":"OP"}]}
},
{"@id":2,
"field1":"qwerty",
"@field2":{"name":"my_name", "name2":"my_name_2"},
"field3":{"event":[{"event_type":"OP"}]}
}
]') as json_data
)
SELECT y.value,
       y.value:"@id"::number as id,
       y.value:field1::string as field1,
       y.value:"@field2"::variant as field2,
       y.value:field3::variant as field3,
       y.value:"@field2":name::varchar as name
FROM x,
LATERAL FLATTEN (input=>json_data) y;
```

Comment: Thanks. Didnt know about the "input". Works fine.

Comment: What if I want to select the "name" from @field2?

Comment: @Cristian I've modified the code above to include selecting the "name" for you.

Comment: Thanks @mike ! Works perfect. I also added yet another "later flatten" because there's another array. Everything works fine.